# Get words between "<" and ">" in .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have written a program to identify tags(between < and >) in a string. From the below string I am able to get `<P>`, `<OL>` and `<LI>` . Div is not getting any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
 string yy = @"<P>&nbsp;</P><OL><LI><DIV align=center>fjsdhfsdjf</DIV></LI><LI>";

 MatchCollection allMatchResults = null;
 var regexObj = new Regex(@"<\w*>");
 allMatchResults = regexObj.Matches(yy);
```

Answer (score 0):

DIV is not begin matched because \w is not matching spaces. Use new Regex(@"<[^>]+>");

Comment: If you want the tag name only regex shall be something like @"<(\w+)\s[^>]*>" and you will need to get the first group in the match

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting Div because it has got attribute. Use `.*?` to include attributes or any text.

```
var regexObj = new Regex(@"<\w.*?>");
```

You can use [Html Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to easily parse and manipulate the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`\w*` will match only alfanemeric characters. 
Here problem lies in space and `=`

Quick solution:
`<[^>]+>` instead of `<\w*>`

But You may want to consider this:
[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is wrong, should be something like

```
@"<[^>]+>"
```

Also, if you have to do a lot of regexes like this, maybe it's better to use something like [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It allows you to parse out the html into node lists that you can iterate through.
Samples can be found [here](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples).

Answer (score 0):

I believe more in this method we are using this one daily where I work.
its a translation company so we translate xml, html, php files to different languages.

```
var myRegex= new Regex(@"(<[^>]+>)");
```

here is just the regex:

```
(<[^>]+>)
```